# Optimize React - Node Performance

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I am using React and Node (MERN Stack).

In react, the component data is received from the Node Server.
So, every time if make any changes to the database, the new entire JSON is sent to the front-end via sockets.
Just wondering, if instead of have to send the entire JSON (updated part+ old part) can I just send the changes and it could rendered in React.

Thanks

Comment: isnt that configured on your backend websocket? modify how the message is being sent.

Comment: In terms of size - how large is the problem at the moment?

Comment: The JSON is not more than 3KB, but my application will be used simultaneously by around 2000 people (a selection sort of app)

Comment: So if I just send the updated content instead of the entire JSON it would reduce my bandwidth charge..

Comment: If you consistently don't need all the data that is being returned, modify the return value on the backend. Perhaps break into smaller functions and only call what you need.